# Starting kit in RoleMaster during an unusual start

Tags: gm-techniques, magic-items, campaign-development, rolemaster, rolemaster-standard-system

In RM players tend to start out with gear that they choose (or can afford to buy based on their wealth roll) to a limited degree and get rolls on the Special Items tables and what have you.

I'm presently working on a campaign in which the players start out in a 'prison realm' with no memory of what has happened prior to their incarceration (in fact, with no knowledge that they are incarcerated; a magical form of amnesia).

How can I introduce these items at the start, based on the fact that they *could* be cursed (i.e. rolled under 11 on my table) and melded to the player (also, technically they should have attuned already to the items prior to their use)?  Or should I even allow them, based on the fact that the players are in a prison realm (though this would be counter-productive to the realm they start in)?

My main problem, here, is incorporating the items without giving away too much about their usage prior to the campaign's start.  I want to trickle feed memories to each of them as they progress through the campaign.

Comment: Just for reference; which version of RM are you playing? RMSS, RM, RMC2, RMClassic?

Comment: Most likely RM Classic.  We haven't done this for quite a while (pretty rusty!), so it's a bit of a re-learning curve without the added rules and regs in RM2!

Comment: That will save you a lot of hassle, believe me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting items are an important boost for a lot of RM classes, power point adders and multipliers particularly can stop spellcasting classes being pretty weak in PP.

However if your whole world is going to be "item free" then these are not appropriate tables to use.

So here are options I'd suggest.

- Ditch the tables entirely, don't allow anyone to start with items.
- Pickup later, have the players find the items later on; if only they are attuned to them (penalty for anyone else to try and attune) then they should naturally aquire the items
- Tattoos, Tattoo magic allows bonding of spells and items onto a character (RMC V) so instead of an item carve a sigil onto the character. Instead of the possibility of losing the item check any crit that damages the location where the tattoo is for a chance of damaging the tattoo.
- Have them have swallowed the items!
- have the items given to them by a bribed guard before their inevitable escape.
- What the hey; start them with the items anyway.

Comment: It's not that the campaign is going to be item free - it's more that the players will start without knowledge of events in (what could be called) the outside world.  Players will start in the prison realm, as above, but it's whether I should give the items at the start or withhold them until later.  I had toyed with the idea of making them very powerful and waiting for them to escape the prison (many levels later), but I'd like them to have them at the start, bearing in mind their 'amnesia'. It's how I incorporate them at the start that is key.

Comment: Gotcha, added a couple more options then

Comment: I like the idea of the tattoos!  Not bad - I'd never considered that. Technically the bribed guard won't work because of the nature of the prison (trust me - it's all pretty complicated!). Swallowing the items would be interesting ... especially for the two handed sword! °_o. Picking up later was definitely an option, perhaps in one of the Arcane Towers or the Tower of Lightening later, as rewards for completing the levels of the Tower.

Comment: I suppose, though, the main dilemma is how to introduce the items. Do you think I should give them 'Memory' roles at the right time to see if they remember how to use the items, or should I handle the role for them, so I can control the gradual power being introduced to them?

Comment: Either would work; you can play it how you think; you can work the items as a memory trigger to slowly getting fragments of memory back, or they just -know- how to use them, they don't know why...

Comment: Note, if you wait a while before accepting you might get some more helpful answers :)

Comment: True ... forgive me, then - I'll uncheck that for a couple of days! ;o)

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on what do you want the players to do on the first session.

If you want them to wander around, fight things and have an almost normal session but with amnessia, you need them to have the objects.

If you want them to be nearly naked, in an "awakening alone" style, and start wondering about everything and having even a medium-sized dog to be big challenge, you need them to have no objects.

Which tone do you want for the campaign?

Besides, if you decide for not giving the objects, use those options to give them other advantages, like tattoos (from Rob's answer), allies (yet unknown for them), extra resistences, and so on.

Comment: The players will wake-up on a moor (in the prison realm) with a young woman urgently shaking them awake, hurrying them to follow her before night falls... The initial part of the campaign is very guided, lessening off to carrots-and-sticks and then guided once more a little later. It will be fairly high powered campaign after a few levels, so the items would be useful, hence the slow reveal of power detailed in my posts on Rob's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Envite.  I've +1'd you as your points are quite valid in some respects.

Comment: We're here to help :)